# How to remove key from another array that holds values?

Tags: php, arrays

let's suppos we have the following two arrays

Let's suppose this is called `$array1`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jack
            [Height] => 190
            [Shoe Size] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Rose
            [Height] => 160
            [Shoe Size] => 52
        )

)
```

Suppose this is called `$array2`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name
    [1] => Shoe Size
)
```

Now, what I need to do, is to keep the keys in `$array1` which are found in `$array2` as values, so the output I'm expecting is something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jack
            [Shoe Size] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Rose
            [Shoe Size] => 52
        )

)
```

I tried array_intersect and array_intersect_key but they're both failing. does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: may not be most efficient, but a simple foreach loop would be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `array_intersect_key` with `array_flip`

```
$array3 = array_flip($array2);
foreach($array1 as &$a) {
   $a = array_intersect_key($a, $array3);
}
```

Comment: Not quite working, but I get your concept and might be able to work with it.

Comment: @ChosenWann Works exactly as expected. `$array1` gets modified directly, if you want the output to be stored in a brand new array, replace `$a = ` with `$newarray[] = `.